# How enable PHP soap extension on server in cpanel

Tags: php, magento

I will try to install magento on server using cpanel but when i am installing it PHP extension "soap" must be loaded. error show in follwing image. enable SOAP module in php pear but it show error php extension soap must be loaded.

[image]

Comment: You may consult your host provider to see why they are not loading this extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Magento website you can find all the requirements for the server specification. Have a look at these and make sure your server meets them all.

[Magento System Requirements](http://magento.com/resources/previous-magento-system-requirements)

Make sure you have decent resources as Magento does require quite a lot in comparison to other eCommerce platforms.

If you don't have a VPS or root access to your server ask your hosting provider to install all the necessary modules.